# Problem with brackets[?] in css selector in Selenium-python

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-rc

Below is my script which check is element present. When I give this selector:

```
css=input[name='flightSearchParam[3].originAirport']
```

in Selenium Ide it find me this element, but when I run this in selenium rc it can't find it. I think that it is a problem with brackets.

What I must to change to find this element by selenium rc?

I run it at Windows XP and Polish Culture

Script is ready to run.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 5555, "*chrome", "http://www.aa.com/")
        self.selenium.start()


def test_untitled(self):
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open("/international/internationalSplashAccess.do?countryCodeForIP=PL")
    sel.click("localeSubmit")
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
    for i in range(60):
        try:
            if sel.is_element_present("aa-hp-multi-city-link2"): break
        except: pass
        time.sleep(1)
    else: self.fail("time out")
    sel.click("aa-hp-multi-city-link2")
    sel.click("flightSearchForm.button.reSubmit")
    sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")

    for i in range(60):
        try:
            if sel.is_element_present(u"css=input[name='flightSearchParam[3].originAirport']"): break
        except: pass
        time.sleep(1)
    else: self.fail("time out")

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.stop()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Body for :

```
conn.request("POST", "/selenium-server/driver/", body, headers)

 u'cmd=isElementPresent&1=css%3Dinput%5Bname%3DflightSearchParam%5B2%5D.originAirport%5D&sessionId=02b3341a3fee46f5a1e6d9c13d6e8916'
```

**EDIT**

I change it to `sel.is_element_present("dom=document.getElementsByName('flightSearchParam[3].originAirport')[0]"):`

and it find this element. But, I still don't know why css doesn't work here :/

Comment: could you post your html code that you want to match

Comment: I think you'd be better off employing a selector other than CSS (XPath, maybe?)

Answer (score 2):

if the HTML code is

```
<input name="flightSearchParam[3].originAirport">
```

Then the CSS Selector for it will be

```
css=input[name='flightSearchParam\[3\].originAirport']
```

You have to escape the bracket which has a specific meaning for CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that may gain you some insight towards a solution for your problem:

Firefox Selenium IDE returned this target during a recording:

`css=input[name="keywords"]`

the correct CSS selector argument to obtain this element turned out to be (selenium 2.41):

`solution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="keywords"]')`

So, in your case, this might work:

```
css= 'input[name="flightSearchParam[3].originAirport"]'
solution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css)
```

Note: in the Python Selenium, I've never needed to escape brackets which indicate indices...

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the brackets with backslashes.

Comment: u"css=input[name='flightSearchParam[3/].originAirport'/]" doesn't work, too

Comment: sorry, I mean sel.is_element_present(u"css=input[name='flightSearchParam[3\].originAirport'\]"): doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears RC doesn't translate the escape sequence. I would recommend using XPath Attributes. In your case it would be -

```
sel.is_element_present("//input[@name='flightSearchParam[3].originAirport']")
```